# has the wrong number of column. should be 2

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I read all topics about this error, but don't understand how i can fix it in my code. Help me please.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [ru/itpark/config/PersistenceConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: A Foreign key refering ru.itpark.model.UserAnswers from ru.itpark.model.TheoreticTask has the wrong number of column. should be 2
```

User class

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {

    @Id
    //@EmbeddedId
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column
    private String userName;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    private String name;


    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_answers",
            joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private List<UserAnswers> userAnswers;

}
```

PracticTask class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="practic_tasks")
public class PracticTask {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column( name = "theme_id")
    private int themeId;

    @Column
    private String question;

    @Column
    private String answer;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_answers",
            joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "practic_task_last"),
            inverseJoinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private List<UserAnswers> userAnswers;

}
```

Theme class

```
    @Data
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Entity
    @Table(name="themes")
    public class Theme {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        int id;


        @Column
        private String name;


        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "practic_tasks",
                joinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(name = "theme_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
        private List<PracticTask> practicTaskList;

        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "theoretic_tasks",
                joinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(name = "theme_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
        private List<TheoreticTask> theoreticTaskList;

        @OneToMany
        @JoinTable(name = "user_answers",
                joinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(name = "theme_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns =
                @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
        private List<UserAnswers> userAnswers;

    }
```

TheoreticTask class

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="theoretic_tasks")
public class TheoreticTask {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column( name = "theme_id")
    private int themeId;

    @Column
    private String question;

    @Column( name = "first_answer")
    private String firstAnswer;

    @Column( name = "second_answer")
    private String secondAnswer;

    @Column( name = "third_answer")
    private String thirdAnswer;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_answers",
            joinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "theoretic_task_last"),
            inverseJoinColumns =
            @JoinColumn(name = "id"))
    private List<UserAnswers> userAnswers;
}
```

UserAnswer class

```
@Entity
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Table(name = "user_answers")
public class UserAnswers implements Serializable {
    @EmbeddedId
    private UserAnswersPK id;

    @Column(name = "theoretic_task_last")
    private int theoreticTaskLast;

    @Column(name = "practic_task_last")
    private int practicTaskLast;

    @Column(name = "practic_answer_count")
    private int practicAnswerCount;



    @Column(name = "theoretic_answer_count")
    private int theoreticAnswerCount;
}
```

UserAnswerPK class

```
@Embeddable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class UserAnswersPK implements Serializable {
    @Column(name="user_id")
    protected int user_id;
    @Column(name="theme_id")
    protected int theme_id;
}
```

So i read that i need to make JoinColumns but didn't understand.

[This is picture of db dependencies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzJzt.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your mapping has many problems. I think it will be good if you read before doing such relations unless you are learning.

---

It is always better to define the join mapping on the `ManytoOne` side rather than the `OnetoMany` side and I don't think you need a join table based on your database relationship diagram and your join table names.

I will show you mapping relation between UserAnswers and TheoreticTask. You need to change this similarly in all your (1..n) relations.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="theoretic_tasks")
public class TheoreticTask {
    // Other Columns and Relations 

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="theoreticTask")
    private List<UserAnswers> userAnswers;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_answers")
public class UserAnswers implements Serializable {
    // Other Columns and Relations 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "theoretic_task_last")
    private TheoreticTask theoreticTask;
}
```